# making an android app to hide files using java

Tags: android, security

I am making an android application. I would like to know as to how to make a program to hide files from the android phone.Like the "Hide it pro" application

Comment: Hide files and do *what*? One of the options is to move them to encrypted container (for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are three options:

- Move the file in a directory which is not visible to other apps.
- Encrypt the files and let them *public* (that means accessable for other apps)
- Add into your directory where the files are inside a `.nomedia` file. But note that this just *hide* the files from the `MediaScanner`. But it will be simple accessable for other apps if they look into your directory.

By the way your operating system does not matter in any way. Just the target platform counts.

Answer (score 0):

> "Hiding your files from the Media Scanner
>
> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory
>   (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's
>   media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps
>   like Gallery or Music."

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

This won't hide files from the OS (or "the android phone") but it will prevent MediaScanner from picking them up and displaying them in built in apps. NOTE: In Android 4.0 there was an issue where existing indexed files were/are not forgotten if a NEW .nomedia file is created. To work around this create a new directory, add the .nomedia file, and move content you want to hide there.

Comment: How do I go about it. I can create an android application, is there more tutorials where I can make one hide it pro app